# PowerAutomate http request fails where the same request from Postman works fine

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to communicate with an API using the HTTP Action in Power Automate. With this specific API I am getting the error "BadRequest. Http request failed as the content stream was not valid: 'Found invalid data while decoding.'."

I have no problems communicating with that API using Postman and with identical headers.

I also have control over the API if there is any settings that needs to be changed there to get it to work with PA.

The API is using simple token authentication and I have removed it and the url from the images below. Except of that it is exactly the settings I am using.

Settings in PA:
[image]

Settings in Postman
[image]

Response in Postman
[image]

Any pointers that I can investigate to resolve this issue would be greatly apricated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off **Automatic decompression** in the settings of HTTP Request step.

It fixed the same problem on my tenant.
[image]